# positive X-Y coordinate graph using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates

I want to create a positive X-Y plane in a mesh format using three.js. Also I want to be able to click on any point of intersection and get the coordinate values. The view should be like a graph paper.

```
Design.prototype.mouseUp = function (event) {

    var material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({
        color:0xffeedd  , dashSize:2 , gapSize:2
    });
    this.container.offsetHeight = 30 , this.container.offsetWidth = 70;
    var a = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i <= this.container.offsetWidth ; i++) {
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -90 + a,-50, 0 ) );
        geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -90 + a, 50, 0 ) );

        var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
        this.scene.add( line);
        a = a + 1;
    }

    var b = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j <= this.container.offsetHeight; j++) {
        var geometry1 = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry1.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -90,-50 +b , 0 ) );
        geometry1.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  90,-50 +b , 0 ) );

        var line1 = new THREE.Line( geometry1, material );
        this.scene.add( line1);
        b = b + 1;
    }

};

Design.prototype.onDocumentMouseMove = function( event ) {

    mouseX = event.clientX - (this.container.offsetWidth * 0.5);
    mouseY = event.clientY - (this.container.offsetHeight-window.innerHeight * 0.875);

};

Design.prototype.onDocumentMouseDown = function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    alert("X: " + mouseX + " Y: " + mouseY);
    var projector = new THREE.Projector();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( mouseX / this.container.offsetWidth )*(2-1), - ( mouseY / this.container.offsetHeight )*(2+1), 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ){

        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size / 4), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(intensity));
        sphere.position = intersects[ 0 ].point;
        scene.add(sphere);
    }
};

//three.js code

window.vv = {};
window.vv.messages = {

NO_CONTAINER: "No Container provided."
};
function DesignSpace() {

    this.activeDesign = 0;
this.designes = [];
}

DesignSpace.prototype.getDesignByIndex = function(index) {

    var returnValue = null;
if (index < this.designes.length) {
    returnValue = this.designes[index];
}
return returnValue;
};

DesignSpace.prototype.setActiveDesign = function(index) {

this.activeDesign = index;
};

DesignSpace.prototype.addDesign = function(container) {

var design = new Design(container);
this.designes.push(design);
return design;
};

DesignSpace.prototype.run = function() {

var design = window.vv.designSpace.getDesignByIndex(window.vv.designSpace.activeDesign);
design.getRenderer().render(design.getScene(), design.getCamera());
window.requestAnimationFrame(window.vv.designSpace.run);
};

function Design(container) {

this.renderer = null,
this.scene = null,
this.camera = null,
this.cube = null,
this.animating = null,
this.light = [];
this.grid = null;
this.container = container;
}

Design.prototype.setUp = function() {

if (!this.container) {
    console.log(window.vv.NO_CONTAINER);
    return null;
}
this.container = document.getElementById(this.container);
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
this.renderer.setSize(this.container.offsetHeight, this.container.offsetHeight);
this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, this.container.offsetWidth / this.container.offsetHeight, 1, 4000);
this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);

if (this.light && !this.light.length) {

    this.light.push(new Light({intensity: 1.0, x: 0, y: 1, z:1}));
}
for (var i in this.light) {

    this.scene.add(this.light[i].getLight());
}

this.addMouseHandler();

};
Design.prototype.addMouseHandler = function (event) {

this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', $.proxy(this.mouseUp, this), false);
this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', $.proxy(this.onDocumentMouseMove, this), false);
this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', $.proxy(this.onDocumentMouseDown, this), false);

};
```

Comment: The X, Y, Z co-ordinates always start from the center of the canvas. Do you want to start your plane from center and occupy the top right quadrant? Or you want it to occupy entire canvas?

Comment: SO doesn't work like this. You should do something, and then people will help you. Ordering around here will take you nowhere.

Comment: @Farzad My bad. Posted in a hurry. Will keep in mind next time :)

Comment: @AmeerTamboli as u can see, I am using a container so i don't want to occupy the entire canvas. I want the leftmost bottom of the container to coincide with the origin of the canvas i.e.(0,0,0). This way the plotting will be done in the positive X-Y axes only. Will that be okay?

Comment: Can you include your `three.js` code too? One way is to use simple 2D plane geometry in `three.js`. Is your graph paper static, and won't move during page presentation? If yes, you can simply get mouse coordinates by an event.

Comment: I need to resize my container when the window is resized. Can this be done using 2D plane geometry?

Comment: @Farzad the mouse event i have used gives result. Only, the onDocumentMouseDown method is returning negative coordinate values. This is because the container is in the leftmost corner of the Design space.

Answer (score 0):

I simply could not follow your code so came up with something like this. It's not complete, and still needs to be worked on. But it's enough to convey the idea in my opinion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>simple X-Y coordinate example with shader</title>
    <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% ;}</style>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>      
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">       
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }           
</script>

<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform vec2 resolution;
    #define SCALES 5.0
    #define X_AXIS -5.0
    #define Y_AXIS -5.0
    #define AXIS_THICKNESS 0.08
    #define ORIGIN_INTENSITY 0.40

    void main()
    {
        vec2 point = -1.0 + 2.0 * ( gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution.xy );
        float aspect_ratio = resolution.x/resolution.y;
        float r = length (point);
        vec3 background = (1.0 - 0.15*r) * vec3(0.7-0.07*(point.y+1.0), 0.8, 1.0);
        vec3 col = vec3(1.0);

        point *= SCALES;
        float f = 1.0 - min (
            min( abs( aspect_ratio*point.x - ceil(aspect_ratio*point.x) ), abs( aspect_ratio*point.x - floor(aspect_ratio*point.x) ) ),
            min( abs( point.y - ceil(point.y) ), abs( point.y - floor(point.y) ) ) );
        col *= (1.0 - pow(f, 40.0));

        col = (abs(aspect_ratio*point.x - aspect_ratio*X_AXIS)<AXIS_THICKNESS || abs(point.y - Y_AXIS)<AXIS_THICKNESS) ? vec3(0.0) : col;
        col = (length (vec2(aspect_ratio*point.x, point.y) - vec2(aspect_ratio*X_AXIS, Y_AXIS)) < ORIGIN_INTENSITY )  ? vec3(0.0) : col;

        gl_FragColor = vec4( col*background , 1.0);
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true});

    window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMousePress, false );

    //assignings happen here
    //more info on https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Uniforms-types
    var uniforms = {
        resolution: {
            type: "v2",
            value: new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight )
        }
    }; 
    var myMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vs' ).textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fs' ).textContent
    });

    camera.position.z = 0.40;
    var itemGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( window.innerWidth / (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight), window.innerHeight / (window.innerWidth+window.innerHeight), 0);
    var itemCube = new THREE.Mesh( itemGeometry, myMaterial );
    scene.add( itemCube );

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        uniforms.resolution.value = new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }

    function onMousePress(e){
        var scale = 10;
        var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        alert(scale*aspect* (e.clientX / window.innerWidth));
        alert(scale* ((window.innerHeight - e.clientY)/ window.innerHeight));
    }

    function render() {

        requestAnimationFrame(render);       
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }
    render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have defined a plane mesh with plane geometry and a custom shader. In the fragment shader, I draw on the plane resembling graph paper. You can play with parameters to see how they affect the final result. In javascript code, see `onWindowResize()`. It's the place I apply window size changes to the camera, renderer, and also update the fragment shader parameter. In `onMousePress(e)`, I collect user-provided data and calculate the coordinates accordingly.
Again, the code is not complete but I provided here to give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks a ton! The code is really helpful. This code expands in the entire window. Can i implement this same code in a container?

Comment: To make the point of origin i.e.(0,0) prominent, 2 rays representing X and Y axes is necessary. Can I use the following code to create the X-axis? var origin = new Vector3(0,0,0); var dest = new Vector(20,0,0); dest.normalize(); var ray = new Ray(origin,dest);

Comment: The rendering happens inside the canvas. You can specify its placement and its size using purely CSS. In the code above, it's occupying 100% of both width and size of its parent (in CSS hierarchy). Beware if you do, you have to reconsider and rewrite written mouse event function.

Comment: The changes I made to fragment shader above will bring in thickness for axises and the origin.

Comment: That's great! The issue with this code is that when the window is minimized then refreshed and maximized, the X-axis vanishes from the scene. Why is this happening?

Comment: No idea. It doesn't happen for me on Chrome in Windows 7.